# designing a ROS diffdrive Robot with rosjava

Tags: ros, rviz, rosjava, topics, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently designing an android robot. I want it to be as much as possible compatible with ROS.

It is a simple differential drive robot with a good odometric precision and sharp sensors.
I would like to know if there is ROS standard node and topic list for diff drive robot?

There is many msg I could be compatible with : pose/ pose2D / posewithcovariance / twist / ...

Of course, I would like my robot being compatible with many stacks, especially Navigation and teleop stack.

I understood that I need to design rviz robot model, is rviz robot model a good starting point?

I'm reading the ROS documentation, but for know I didn't found any specifications that define a standard topics, services and param list.

That would be perfect, if I could have a standard that define : standard node's list / standard services and param / standard topic with type

If no standard like this exists, is there a simple reference ROS robot code that could help?

Sorry for this newbie's question...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33373/designing-a-ros-diffdrive-robot-with-rosjava/) by [Jérôme Monceaux](https://answers.ros.org/users/2283/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-monceaux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could look through the codes of some of these [robots](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots). I personally referred quite a bit to the [turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot)'s because the tutorial is quite complete.

My own experience in working on differential drive robot: [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12599/ros-beginning?answer=18686#post-id-18686). I did not start with the robot model though. That came quite late into the development because I was eager to see things moving.

I would think the topic cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/Twist) is a good starting point, since both the teleop and navigation uses it to control the robot.

Another good reference I found by mwise of willow garage: [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/31705/building-your-own-ros-stack-for-a-new-robot-based)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2